# Drive keeps rebooting and wait for manual fsck

Tags: fsck

This is what my datacenter says

> I've connected monitor to your server and it looks like it was
>   rebooting and is waiting for manual fschk again. Have you rebooted
>   your server?

Then fdcservers would do the manual fschk. Server is online again. But the next day, same thing happen again.

What should I do

I suspected it's hardware.

How do I know which SSD need to be replaced?

If I got to check logs, which logs I should see.

Comment: have you checked the logs ??

Comment: Take a look at the `dmesg` output. Sounds like the drive is failing to me.

Comment: You will need to be more specific and provide any errors on the server (which appear in places such as the output of `dmesg`). Without any more details your question may get voted to be closed as too broad a question.

Comment: I am not asking for what's wrong. I am asking for what to do. Running dmesg is the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the SMART data of your hard disk (replace `/dev/sda` with the name of your hard disk, repeat this process for every disk listed in `cat /proc/partitions`):

```
smartctl -a /dev/sda | less
```

Also run a selftest on the hard disk. This may take several hours, depending on the hard disk size:

```
smartctl -t long /dev/sda
```

When it's completed, read the result with the `smartctl -a` command as shown above. The section `SMART Self-test Log` contains the selftest result.